# How can I raise the brightness of just the voronoi part of this shader?

Tags: texturing, shaders, lighting, emission

I found a voronoi setup that looks kind of like stars. I want to increase the brigthness to make the stars look like they're glowing. If I raise the emission, it can add too much blinding light to the scene however. Is there another way I can increase the brightness of the white stars while keeping the blue the same and also without adding light pollution to the rest of the scene? Below are my images and node setup.

[image: Node Setup]

[image: Low emission]

[image: Higher emission]

[image: Node setup 2]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to brighten just the "stars", use a second ColorRamp to isolate just the white values (against a  black background). Then, use a math node to multiply this by *some value* (depending on your desired brightness - higher is brighter) before adding it back to the original (colored) texture.

[image: Glow]

Comment: This is much closer to what I'm trying to get. Thank you! But now I can't get the blue sky. It's all black with white stars. I added my new node setup to my post at the bottom. I'm pretty sure it's identical to yours. My add node doesn't have color options or a fac option though. It just has value options. I'm on Blender 2.91. If you're not sure, I can probably work with this though.

Comment: The problem is that you used a _Math Node_ for your add operation. You can see from the color of the input "dots" that it deals in black and white values. I used a _MixRGB Node_. which deals in color values, as indicated by the yellow "dots". Remember to switch the operation from "mix" to "add".

Comment: Oh wow ok. Yup that was it. Thanks a bunch!